# Keras neural network outputting function parameters / how to construct loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I'm working on a Keras/TensorFlow based neural network. I am trying to do something a bit different.

Normally, the output layer of the network produces an output tensor (i.e. a list of numbers). Then those numbers are compared directly to a target list of training data (the labels) using a loss function such as mean squared error.

However, I would instead like the output layer of the network to be a list of numbers that serve as **function parameters**. The function operates on these parameters to produce a new list of numbers. The loss function then becomes the MSE between the function output and the labels (instead of, as would normally be the case, the MSE between the output layer and the labels).

I understand that I need to write a Keras custom loss function that computes the values of the target function from the output layer values, then computes and returns the MSE between the target function output and the labels. I also realize that all of this needs to be done within the TensorFlow graph, and that the target function needs to be differentiable so that gradients can be computed. I believe I understand all of this well enough.

Here's what I can't wrap my head around. Let's say there are four neurons in the output layer - call them a, b, c, d. Each of them is a separate parameter to the target function F(a, b, c, d). Let's say I iterate F(a, b, c, d) 20 times and get a set of 20 values. That is, F(a, b, c, d, 1); F(a, b, c, d, 2); etc. Then I just want to take the MSE between these 20 values and the 20 values in the corresponding label tensor. That will be the loss function.

I just don't understand the Keras/Tensorflow backend well enough to know how to obtain the individual elements of the output tensor. How do I address the zeroth, first, second, etc elements in this tensor so that I can use them to compute the function values? I know how to perform operations on whole tensors, but I don't understand how to address individual tensor elements.

I hope I've explained the issue sufficiently clearly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you need to make this more concrete to see if it is feasible. How will the output be used as function parameters? Note that neural network individual outputs are vectors while parameters are matrices if we are talking about a neural network with more than a single neuron. Suppose you do so, what will you use as an input to that function then? (It's cool to think about questions like this by the way, it creates a chain reaction of other questions that help understanding)

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify further. Imagine the output layer has four neurons. Each neuron outputs a scalar value. So there are four scalars a, b, c, d coming from the output layer. I would like to compute a function F(a, b, c, d, x) = A*sin(b*x+c)+d. For every training operation/time interval, I will run F(a, b, c, d, 1) through F(a, b, c, d, 20) to generate 20 outputs. Then I will calculate MSE between these 20 outputs and the 20 values in the label tensor.

Comment: In F(a,b,c,d,x) what is x?

Comment: X is the values 1 through 20. That is, I want to generate 20 elements by running Asin(B*1+C)+D, Asin(B*2+C)+D, etc. The goal is to have a 20 element label tensor, and a 20 element output tensor, so that I can take the MSE between matching elements.

Comment: To clarify, it is not important to me whether X is a tensor containing [1, 2, 3, ..., 20], or whether I iteratively call F(a, b, c, d, 1), then F(a, b, c, d, 2), etc. All that matters to me is that I generate a 20-element output tensor to match the 20-element label tensor.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, are you proposing to use the same input x both as input to the neural network that predicts a,b,c and d and to the function that then estimates a single value?

Comment: I'm sorry that I am still not managing to communicate this.  Please forget about X, it seems to be causing confusion. I will try another approach. I need to compute a loss function to compare the network output against the target labels. The thing that makes this situation unusual is that instead of comparing the output **directly**, I need to treat the output as a set of function parameters and then calculate MSE on the **function output** vs the target labels.

Comment: Let's say I have a label tensor that contains 20 elements. I need to generate a 20 element output tensor to compare against it. My network has four output neurons which generate scalar values a, b, c, d. I have a function F = a * sin(b * x + c) + d. In order to build up the 20 element output tensor, I am going to run F 20 times, using values 1, ..., 20 for x. So element 1 of the output tensor is a * sin(b + c) + d. Element 2 is a * sin(b*2 + c) + d. Et cetera.

Comment: X is just a placeholder for the constant values [1, 2, ..., 20] that I use when running F. X **always** takes the same values [1, 2, ..., 20]. It is just a constant. The only purpose of X is that I need to run F 20 times so that I have a 20 element output vector that I can compare to the 20 element target label in the loss function. I hope that this is clearer; I can't think of any clearer way to state the issue. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I failed to understand what you were after!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the predicted result and the labels must have the same shape, we should create an entire model, containing the function you want (not leaving the function to the loss function).

Later we can take the output of a previous layer, which will be the desired parameters.

So, suppose you've got your model prepared up to the layer that outputs the parameters (A `Dense(4)` most likely, which will output 4 parameters **for each input sample**).

Let's add two lambda layers after it.

- One to output the 4 unique parameters, independent from samples, because you will want to retrieve them later
- One to be the actual function `a*sin(bx + c) + d`

So:

```
#add them to your model the usual way you do
model.add(Lambda(getParameters,output_shape=(4,),name='paramLayer'))
model.add(Lambda(yourFunction,output_shape=(1,),name='valueLayer'))
```

Where:

```
import keras.backend as K

def getParameters(x):

    #since x comes in as a batch with shape (20,4) -- (or any other batch size different from 20)

    #let's condense X in one sample only, because we want only 4 elements, not 20*4 elements
    xCondensed = K.mean(x,axis=0,keepdims=True)
        #I'm using keepdims because we will need that x end up with the same number of samples for compatibility purposes (keras rules)

    #let's expand x again (for compatibility purposes), now repeating the 4 values 20 (or more) times
    return K.ones_like(x) * xCondensed



def yourFunction(x):


    #now x has 4 parameters (assuming you had a Dense(4) before these lambda layers)
    a = x[:,0]
    b = x[:,1]
    c = x[:,2]
    d = x[:,3]

    #creating the 20 (or more) iterations
    ones = K.ones_like(x[:,0])
    iterationsStartingAt1= K.cumsum(ones)
    iterationsStartingAt0= iterationsStartingAt1 - 1
    iterations = #choose one of the above


    return (a * K.sin((b*iterations) + c)) + d
```

Now you can train this model passing the labels.

When you want to retrieve the four parameters, you need another model, that ends earlier:

```
from keras.models import Model

paramModel = Model(model.inputs,model.get_layer('paramLayer').output)
params = paramModel.predict(testOrTrainData)
```

The result will be shaped like (20,4), but all the 20 lines will be repeated.

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I needed. I had started to realize that a lambda layer was going to be the way to go, but it's helpful to have your explanation of the complete solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great :) -- Please consider marking this answer as correct then.

Comment: Done! - That check mark is not the most obvious piece of UI.